# jquery and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I develop a **web application** which has worked very well, than I move this **web application** into [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com/) and my domain is [ks-hospitaldemo.tk](http://ks-hospitaldemo.tk/). Now my problem is after upload my **web application** into **free server** my all **JavaScript** and **jQuery** are not worked. I use the following code ::

```
  <footer id="indexFooter">

  </footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/menuBar.js"></script>
```

All my **JavaScript** file is placed into **_javasSript** folder in server.

Then I check my code and find some code which is not done by me, probably hosting server. This code is given below::

```
<!--//--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php">
</script> <!--//--><script language="javascript">
<!--bmi_SafeAddOnload(bmi_load,"bmi_orig_img",0);//-->
</script>
```

Please help me to find my problem.

Comment: perhaps you should add `/` to `_javascript/jquery-....` to be `/_javascript/...`

Comment: still no result. would you please visit this site? this might help me a lot

Comment: leepowers gave you a correct answer, I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new web server is using case-sensitive file lookups. The exact name of the directory is `_javaScript` but it's referenced in the HTML as `_javascript`. Use the exact name to fix the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javaScript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javaScript/menuBar.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the permissions on the _javascript folder. Also, 000 Webhost is known to have problems with Google Analytics. If you have a Google Analytics code on your site, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Some proxy / CDN services / providers inject or transform code in your .html pages to "speed up" data transfer. I had the same problem when accessing my website from a smartphone.

The solution that worked for me was to append Cache-control in the head of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-transform"/>
```